# TLS Session Resumption for static content and JavaScript

Tags: tls, session-management, performance

This is an observation of SSL/TLS Resumption that maybe someone can help explain why SSL/TLS resumption is NOT shared between static assets and Javascript.

Basically, I tested using two pages: pageA and pageB.

- First visit pageA, which does TLS initial connection as expected for the image.
- Then clicking pageB, the "img" tag reuse TLS (no TLS negotiation), BUT javascript does a new TLS negotiation instead (seen in web browser debugger).

So, the question is why JS does not re-use the TLS session?  I search around but nothing is mentioned specifically about this separation.

```
<html>
<body><h2>PageA</h2>
<p><a href="pageB.html">Go to page B</a></p>
<p><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<html>
<body><h2>PageB</h2>
<p><a href="pageA.html">Go to page A</a></p>
<p><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" /></p>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('GET', "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
http.send();
</script>
```

Comment: *"... seen in web browser debugger ..."* - what exactly you see in the browser debugger? That a new TLS handshake is done (as expected when a new TCP connection is setup) or that the TLS session from the previous question was not resumed (TLS handshake can happen with or without session resumption).

Comment: What I see is the second one -- the TLS session from the previous call (img tag) was not resumed (xhr) -- even though statements I see online make me believe that it should.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are seeing. Does it explicitly say "session resume" in the browser or does it just say "SSL" or similar? How exactly did you determine the difference between a TLS handshake with session resume and a TLS handshake without session resume? Can you please edit your question to include what exactly you are seeing and not only what your interpretation of this is?